# How to use RegExp in React-Native Webview's injectedJavaScript prop?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, wkwebview

When I use regexp in React-Native-Webview's injectedJavaScript prop, an error `Unterminated regular expression literal error` will be thrown and the regexp will not be honored.

**How should I use regexp in injectedJavaScript?** **If not, is there a workaround I can use?**

Minimal reproducible code is below:

```js
// this won't work
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser' }}
  injectedJavaScript={`const regE = /\n|\r/`}
/>

// this won't work as well
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser' }}
  injectedJavaScript={`const regE = new RegExp(/\n|\r/);`}
/>

// this will work
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser' }}
  injectedJavaScript={`const regE = /A*B*C*/`}
/>
```

- OS: iOS
- OS version: 13.3.1
- react-native version: 0.61.2
- react-native-webview version: 8.1.2

Check the bug screen below as well.

[image]

Full Error Message:

Error evaluating injectedJavaScript: This is possibly due to an unsupported return type. Try adding true to the end of your injectedJavaScript string. Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SyntaxError: Unterminated regular expression literal '/', WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}

Comment: It may be an escape character issue

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Wild guess. Try a pattern without backslashes, see if it compiles. Can also put a `;` at the end of the declaration

Comment: I could use a pattern without backslashes without error. Thanks! But I do need the patterns that have backslashes. What should I do then?

Comment: Sounds like it's being interpreted as an escape character or something in the webview, so a single backslash isn't enough in the pattern. Try double-escaping your backslashes, it may work: `/\\n|\\r/;`

Comment: wow it does work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not writing plain Javascript - you're writing Javascript *inside the webview*, through which your syntax has to be evaluated first. To use a literal backslash in `injectedJavaScript` (eg, for `\r`), put two backslashes instead (`\\r`):

```
injectedJavaScript={`const regE = new RegExp(/\\n|\\r/);`}
```

I think that

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser' }}
  injectedJavaScript={`const regE = new RegExp(/\n|\r/);`}
/>
```

takes the `\n` in the string literal to be a newline in the code, and equivalent to:

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-html-parser' }}
  injectedJavaScript={`const regE = new RegExp(/
|\r/);`}
/>
```

(and the same thing is done with the `\r`). But newlines aren't permitted in regular expression literals.