# How to use regexp without built-in regexp in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

In a [weird case of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910417/how-to-use-regexp-in-react-native-webviews-injectedjavascript-prop), I cannot use the built-in regexp in js when I try to inject js to WebView.

What could be my second best thing to use? I basically use regexp to detect:

- line-feed(`someString.match(/\n/)`)
- cartridge return(`someString.match(/\r/)`)
- split string into words(`manyWords.split(/\s+/)`)

But other ways to achieve regexps without js built-in regexp will be appreciated as well.

Comment: Please show us the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: why not use 3rd party lib like https://github.com/aaditmshah/regex

Comment: what exactly is the use case again? Perhaps it'd help you and us if you elaborate? Your previous post is as opaque as this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript's built-in `string.prototype.indexOf` and `string.prototype.split`, there's really no need for regex for those cases.

For line feed you can use `someString.indexOf('\n') > -1`

For cartridge return you can use `someString.indexOf('\r') > -1`

For splitting to words you can use `manyWords.split(' ')`

Incase you want the split a string that contains line breaks to words, you need to nest the split like this:
`manyWords.split('\n').flatMap(function(line) { return line.split(' ');});`